# Welcome messages for different userNames

Tags: python

I want a python code to print greeting messages for users when logged in: if the `userName` is `admin` then it should print "Hello admin you're welcome, would you want to see a status update?", and if the `userName` is other than `admin` then a different welcome message is printed:

I tried the code below but am not getting it right:

```
userNames = ["jack2", "admin", "lucy21", "angeUt", "lacky53"]

userName = "admin"
if userName == "admin":
    # ** print this below if admin is the userName **
    print("Hello " + userName + " you are welcome, would you like to see a status update?")
else:
    print("other message")
    # ** this should be printed when the userName is for example jack2. **
```

Please note I just started python barely a week now.
I just didn't get the code right because am just starting out with programming.

[image]

Comment: Hello. Even if your code didn't work, please post what you tried (hmmm ok you did that, just think of formatting it next time), and the error or result you got, along with what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

The first prompt says to loop through the list of user names, and print a special message if the name is "admin":

```py
def main():
    userNames = ["jack2", "admin", "lucy21", "angeUt", "lacky53"]
    for user in userNames:
        if user == "admin":
            print("Hello admin would you like to see a status report")
        else:
            print("Hello {}".format(user))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check if the username is in the list of names with `user in userNames`.
Then you would just have to check if it's the admin, for the more specific message.

```
userNames = ["jack2", "admin", "lucy21", "angeUt", "lacky53"]

user = "admin"

if user in userNames:
    if user == "admin":
        print ("Hello " + user + " you are welcome, would you like to see a status update?")
    else:
        print ("Hello " + user + " thanks for logging in again.")
```